# Facebook getLoginStatus() function and phonegap not updating status

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I am currently developing an app on Android using phonegap and would like to use Facebook in the app. I have created an app on Facebook called say "Test". When I am not logged into "Test" but I am logged into Facebook (Facebook app on the Android device) and run the getLoginStatus() function I get a response of `unknown` instead of `not_authorized`. Thus my first question is this intended? Am I meant to get a response of `unknown` or is this an error from phonegap and I'm meant to get a response of `not_authorized`.

The second question is, when I login into the Facebook app called "test" everything runs as it should (Facebook user gets registered for "test"). When I call the getLoginStatus() function it works perfectly fine and says I'm connected with no problems.

BUT

If I go into Facebook and remove the app "test" from my FB account and then run the android app again and run the getLoginStatus() function is STILL says that I have the app "test" registered to my Facebook account but this is no the case!! Note that I do in the code make sure that I call the server every time instead of using a cached result by the JS SDK. Now my Second question is. Is this meant to happen? Or if not is it a Facebook or Phonegap problem (Phonegap either keeps getting the cached response or Facebook doesn't update their side quick enough?)

Here is code:

```
function getLoginStatus() 
      {
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
          {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            alert(response.status);
            if (response.status == 'connected') 
            {
              alert('logged in');
                FB.api('/me',function (response) {
                    if (response.error)
                    {
                        alert('There is an error');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(response.name);
                    } 
                });


            }
            else 
            {
              alert('not logged in');
            }
           },true);
      }
```

Any response would really really be appreciated!!

Comment: Can you show us some code?\

Comment: @Roberto Does pep's answer solved your problem? Currently I am stucked on this problem as well. I always got response.status `connected` even  though I already logged out from facebook app. If you have solved it, what did you do?

Comment: Nope pep's answer didn't solve the problem at all. Yet he got the bounty... I didn't end up doing it but what I imagined one must do, is every time you wish post or access a users info, you would have to try catch the errors and react based on that. So if you can't post to their wall it means they removed your fb app and as such you try to catch the error and prompt them to give your fb app access again. (But I never ended up fiishing off my project yet, so I cant say this will work 100%). Please if you figure it out please post the answer here

Answer (score 4):

`When I am not logged into "Test" but I am logged into Facebook (Facebook app on the Android device) and run the getLoginStatus() function I get a response of unknown instead of not_authorized.`

not_authorized: You get not_authorized when the user is logged into facebook but has not authorized your app. If you transfer the guy to facebook homepage, he enters username and password and cancels authorization, thereafter you get not authorized. IF the guy is logged into facebook,and your app hasn't transferred him to fb to authorize yet, you still get not authorized

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

unknown: If the user is not logged into facebook, you get a status of unknown.

So logged in, not authorized : not_authorized
Not Logged in: unknown

`If I go into Facebook and remove the app "test" from my FB account`

I am guessing it takes a while for these changes to propogate. If the user has authorized the app in the current context, it will stay authorized for a while(or until he logs off). I don't think there's anything wrong with this personally

Comment: that's kind of what i meant. Didn't put it the right way. Yeah the op didn't select the answer. It expired by default

Comment: I have read the documentation on FB and the plugin does NOT do what it should do! In the code given above EVEN if the user is logged into Facebook but Not my app on Facebook I get a response of UNKNOWN instead of NOT_AUTHORIZED!(I never get a response of NOT_AUTHORIZED). Also if a user removed my app from their facebook account the getloginstatus()function still reads CONNECTED instead of NOT_AUTHORIZED but Facebook doesn't let me access a user's friends which I should be able to if they connected (Note this is even with the Roundtrips to Facebook's servers set to true! Your answer is useless

Comment: hey I am quoting from the docs. and as pep mentioned, the user login is cached, Not Authorized happens only if the user hasn't logged into your app. Once he does, the response will be connected until he logs out. Even he removes the app from facebook(or so it seems)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a phonegap issue. `unknown` is one of the valid responses from the `getLoginStatus` function. See the [facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) for information about this funciton. There, they describe the `unknown` response as:

> the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)

As to your second question, the problem you are seeing is because by default, the `getLoginStatus` function caches its response for performance reasons. However, they provide you with a way to force a refresh of the status. You can do this by passing a second parameter, `Force` into `getLoginStatus`.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true); // The second parameter, called 'force' by default is False. True signifies that you want to force a call to the server so you can see the latest login status.
```

You can read more about that `Force` parameter by looking at the above API documentation link and searching for the 'Force' parameter.

By the way, I had temporarily deleted the answer as I had answered without knowing how to respond to the second question, but undeleted it after finding out the reason behind your issue.

Comment: I have been looking for hours for this answer, the `, true` made the trick, thank you !